# Python composition example

Tags: python, composition

I have been struggling with an example code that I use to practice and learn Python. Understanding the below's code is not hard, however, if I go line by line I am not sure what the following one does.

```
course_running.add_student(self)
```

How is it possible that we run add_student method of CourseRunning class to a parameter course_running (Student class, enrol method)? 
I would be very grateful if you can provide an explanation how that line of code works?

The full code is provided below.

```html
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, student_number):
        self.name = name
        self.student_number = student_number
        self.classes = []

    def enrol(self, course_running):
        self.classes.append(course_running)
        course_running.add_student(self)


class Department:
    def __init__(self, name, department_code):
        self.name = name
        self.department_code = department_code
        self.courses = {}

    def add_course(self, description, course_code, credits):
        self.courses[course_code] = Course(description, course_code, credits, self)
        return self.courses[course_code]


class Course:
    def __init__(self, description, course_code, credits, department):
        self.description = description
        self.course_code = course_code
        self.credits = credits
        self.department = department
        self.department.add_course(self)

        self.runnings = []

    def add_running(self, year):
        self.runnings.append(CourseRunning(self, year))
        return self.runnings[-1]


class CourseRunning:
    def __init__(self, course, year):
        self.course = course
        self.year = year
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        self.students.append(student)
```

Thanks in advance!
Igor

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. `course_running` is supposed to be an instance of `CourseRunning`, so its method `add_student` receives exactly one argument `student`, which we provide as `self`.

Comment: Maybe you missed name differences?  `CourseRunning` is a class and `course_running` is an object of that class that has already been created.

Answer (score 0):

A CourseRunning object has its list of attending students, and a Student object has a list of courses the student is currently taking.

Say there are `student1` and `running_course1`. We wish to enroll `student1` to `running_course1`. We than run:

```
student1.enroll(running_course1)
```

The `enroll` method does two things:

1. `self.classes.append(course_running)` - which translated to `student1.classes.append(running_course1). So now the course is registered in the student's list.
2. `course_running.add_student(self)` - which translates to `running_course1.add_student(student1)`. This invokes `running_course1.add_student(self, student1)` which adds the student to the course's list.

Comment: Hi Eran. Thanks for providing a nice explanation. From the present code, after using enrol method, I am unable to access student1.classes in order to check the full list of classes the student is taking and also I can not access running_course1.students list in order to check how many students attend the running course. Shouldn't it work that way?

Comment: @igordr You should be able to access these fields, I am not sure why it's not working. However, this should be a separate question, since it is not related to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a full code because no any object is present no method call..

i am providing you a code please run this in your pc.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, student_number):
        self.name = name
        self.student_number = student_number
        self.classes = []

    def enrol(self, course_running):
        print "In enroll method"
        self.classes.append(course_running)
        course_running.add_student(self)


class Department:

    def __init__(self, name, department_code):
        self.name = name
        self.department_code = department_code
        self.courses = {}

    def add_course(self, description, course_code, credits):
        self.courses[course_code] = Course(description, course_code, credits, self)
        return self.courses[course_code]


class Course:

    def __init__(self, description, course_code, credits, department):
        self.description = description
        self.course_code = course_code
        self.credits = credits
        self.department = department
        self.department.add_course(self)

        self.runnings = []

    def add_running(self, year):
        self.runnings.append(CourseRunning(self, year))
        return self.runnings[-1]


class CourseRunning:

    def __init__(self, course, year):
        self.course = course
        self.year = year
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        print "student-->", student
        print "In Add Student"
        self.students.append(student)


course_running = CourseRunning('b.tech', '2011')
obj = Student('student_xyz', "1234")
obj.enrol(course_running)
```

what happening here is we are creating an object of "CourseRunning" class.
and when we call "enroll" method of "Student" class we are passing the object of "CourseRunning" class so we are able to access the method of "CourseRunning" class because "course_running" is a object of "CourseRunning" class so it will access all methods of "CourseRunning" class

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation how objects are passed. In the code above, it should be possible, after enrolment, to access studentName1.classes and runningCourse1.students, where studentName1 and runningCourse1 are instances of Student and CourseRunning objects, respectively. However, I don't get the lists with the content. Do you have any thoughts on this?